# Unity com Firebase + Google Autenticação Como fazer

Tags: firebase, unity3d, autenticação

Estou  precisando de uma ajuda para usar o Firebase com o Google Autenticação na documentação esta muito vago pelo menos para mim.

exemplo é esse código onde eu consigo esses **googleIdToken** e o **googleAcessToken**? Não estou achando em lugar nenhum:

```
Firebase.Auth.Credential credential =
Firebase.Auth.GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(googleIdToken, googleAccessToken);
    auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync was canceled.");
            return;
        }
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.LogError("SignInWithCredentialAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
            return;
        }

        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
        Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
            newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("checkNework");

    });
```

Comment: A [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin?hl=pt-br#authenticate_with_firebase) talvez te ajude.

Comment: Então isso é o que está na documentação porem não encontro essa parte dessas tokens ou como criou/obtenho elas está vago essa informação.

Comment: Experimente este [plugin](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity)